# Help with slitherlink honeycomb

Tags: logical-deduction, slitherlink

[image]

This is the best I can do:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/vqHx7BO]

It makes me think that I'm missing some simple detail.

Answer (score 6):

The puzzle cannot be completed from your current state, so you must have made some invalid deductions.  The forced edges you have are correct except for the bottom two fours.  I suggest undoing all other deductions except the correct forced edges and starting again from there.

In particular,

> the vertical edge in the bottom row is wrong, and if you exclude it the puzzle can easily be completed.